# battery question for DW558 Explorer (small quadrocopter)

Tags: quadcopter, battery

I recently bought a DW558 Quadrocopter (http://www.gearbest.com/rc-quadcopters/pp_110531.html).

After few minutes, the battery is dead. Which is understandable since the battery is so tiny. It is a 3.7V 250mAh battery, included with the Quadrocopter. I was thinking about buying spare batteries for it, and I have few questions about this:

- 1: Can I buy any kind of battery 3.7V 250mAh of the same size or is there any other property I have to pay attention?
- 2: Can I buy batteries of 3.7V and 350mAh (100 more than the included battery) and expect my Quadrocopter to be more "energic"? Is it bad to buy batteries with more mAh ?
- 2b: If I buy few 3.7V 350mAh batteries, will I be able to charge them with the same charger I got with my 3.7V 250 mAh batteries or do I have to buy a specific charger for these too?

(these are the batteries I want to buy, any comment is greatly appreciated: 350mAh batteries x5 http://www.gearbest.com/rc-quadcopter-parts/pp_196991.html and/or 4x 250mAh batteries + charger http://www.gearbest.com/rc-quadcopter-parts/pp_331372.html)

Thank you very much for your input. I think I just discovered my new hobby and I can't wait to have my spare batteries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the links you gave, the 350mAh is slightly larger dimensions than the 250mAh and seems to have the same connector.

- As long as it fits and has the same connector then you can put in anything you want. So long as it is still a Li-Po.
- The "energic"ness of the quad will depend on the C rating of the battery, which is the current rating. A higher C rating battery will react faster to changes in load and hence provide a more snappy response. Although I doubt it will make much difference with such a small quad.
- You should be able to charge them with the same charger, it will just take slightly longer. Since battery chargers work on the voltage and current draw of the battery while charging they will work irrespective of the capacity of the battery.

So just make sure it fits the battery compartment and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also find out that my quad is unstable, one of the rotor (top right) seems to be less effective than the 3 others, which lead the quad to go forth and right at the same time and I can't manage to fly it with ease... I tried to add some weight on the opposite side but it is not very effective. Is there something else I can do about it?

Comment: You can use the rocker switches below and to the side of the control sticks to trim out a drift like that. [This might help](http://uavcoach.com/how-to-fly-a-quadcopter-guide/)

Comment: Oh I feel so dumb! English is not my native language and I couldn't understand this "trim" function in the english documentation... Thank you so much !!